# How do I search only first object in an array of nested objects using ElasticSearch

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, elastica, symfony-2.5, foselasticabundle

I'm using ElasticaBundle and ElasticSearch with Symfony2 in a system I've written. 
A 'person' can have many 'positions' in their work history. The positions are sorted by date desc, and in order to find someone's current position with PHP I retrieve and read the first object in the array.

I am struggling to search only the current or first position using ElasticSearch. I have set the mappings upas nested, and I am able to perform a Nested Query returning a 'person' who has a 'position' that matches all my criteria. What I can't do is work out how to only search for the criteria in the 1st listed 'position'. Does anyone have any ideas to set me off on the right path?

The only options I can think of at the moment are:
maintain an order value in each object so I can pick out the 1st,
or create another field in the entity that only has a relationship, with the 1st position

Answer (score -1):

I've read on the ElasticSearch documentation that this kind of key isn't supported in ElasticSearch, but now I can't find the page in question. Sorry.

In the end I got round by the problem by setting an identifier on the current position, i.e. giving it a identifier of 0 with all other positions numbers in order.